# How to make dynamic changes to popup.html in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to understand how can I make changes to the HTML of popup.html in a Chrome extension that reloads a given URL every x seconds and looks for a certain text in the webpage.

More precisely: the extension's UI has two buttons "Run" and "Stop", respectively running and stopping the reload-and-search function above.
I also wanted to include in the UI a "loading" gif to display when the user clicks on the "Run" button and the extension is searching for the text.  The loading gif should disappear either when the user clicks on the "Stop" button (and the extension stops searching) or when the the text is found on the target website.

The loading gif is inside an invisible  with id="searching" in **popup.html**:

```
<div id="searching" style="display: none;" align="center"><img  src="loading.gif" style="width: auto; height: 30%"/></div>
```

and I tried to reach the desired outcome by adding in **app.js** two functions that change its attributes, as well as `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` (in addition to backround.js):

```
 function showSrc() {
   document.getElementById('searching').style.display ='block';
 } 

 function hideSrc() {
   document.getElementById('searching').style.display ='none';
 }

 document.querySelector('.button-run').addEventListener('click', () => {chrome.runtime.sendMessage('start'); showSrc();});

 document.querySelector('.button-stop').addEventListener('click', () => {chrome.runtime.sendMessage('stop'); hideSrc();});

 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, callback){
   if(message === 'stop') {
     hideSrc();
   } else if(message === 'run') {
     showSrc();
   }
 });
```

As you can see from **app.js**, when the user clicks on "Run" or "Stop", the script not only sends the respective messages to background.js for the extension to perform/stop its reload-and-search function, but also changes the attribute of the  with id="searching" so that the loading gif is visible/invisible in the UI accordingly by calling `showSrc()` or `hideSrc()`, respectively.

However, this works fine only when I stay with the UI open in the tab where I launch the script.  If I switch the tab while the extension is running, then the UI (popup.html) closes and when I reopen it by clicking on the extension's icon, loading.gif is gone although the extension is still running.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried changing manifest.json? From false to true as below:  
```
"background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": true
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it doesn't work.